# How to force encoding for Logstash filters? (umlauts from message not recognized)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to import historical log data into ElasticSearch (Version 5.2.2) using Logstash (Version 5.2.1) - all running under Windows 10.

### Sample log file

The sample log file I am importing looks like this:

```
07.02.2017 14:16:42 - Critical - General - Ähnlicher Fehler mit übermäßger Ödnis
08.02.2017 14:13:52 - Critical - General - ästhetisch überfällige Fleißarbeit
```

### Working configuration

For starters I tried the following simple Logstash configuration *(it's running on Windows so don't get confused by the mixed slashes ;))*:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:/logstash/bin/*.log"
        sincedb_path => "C:\logstash\bin\file_clientlogs_lastrun"
        ignore_older => 999999999999
        start_position => "beginning"
        stat_interval => 60
        type => "clientlogs"
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "clientlogs" {
        elasticsearch {
            index => "logstash-clientlogs"
        }
    }
}
```

And this works fine - I see that input gets read line by line into the index I specified - when I check with Kibana for example those two lines might look like this *(I just ommitted host-name - click to enlarge)*:
[image: image illustrating 2 documents from kibana ui]

### More complex (not working) configuration

But of course this is still pretty flat data and I really want to extract the proper timestamps from my lines and also the other fields and replace `@timestamp` and `message` with those; so I inserted some filter-logic involving [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)-, [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html)- and [date-filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) in between `input`and `output` so the resulting configuration looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:/logs/*.log"
        sincedb_path => "C:\logstash\bin\file_clientlogs_lastrun"
        ignore_older => 999999999999
        start_position => "beginning"
        stat_interval => 60
        type => "clientlogs"
    }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "clientlogs" {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{MONTHDAY:monthday}.%{MONTHNUM2:monthnum}.%{YEAR:year} %{TIME:time} - %{WORD:severity} - %{WORD:granularity} - %{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" ]
    }
    mutate {
       add_field => { 
        "timestamp" => "%{year}-%{monthnum}-%{monthday} %{time}"
        }
        replace => [ "message", "%{logmessage}" ]
        remove_field => ["year", "monthnum", "monthday", "time", "logmessage"]
    }
    date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
        timezone => "Europe/Vienna"
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }
  }
}
output {
    if [type] == "clientlogs" {
        elasticsearch {
            index => "logstash-clientlogs"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I look at those logs for example with Kibana, I see the fields I wanted to add do appear and the timestamp and message are replaced correctly, but my umlauts are all gone *(click to enlarge)*:
[image: image illustrating 2 documents from kibana ui where umlauts have not been recognized and replaced]

### Forcing charset in input and output

I also tried setting

```
codec => plain {
                charset => "UTF-8"
            }
```

for `input` and `output`, but that also did not change anything for the better.

### Different output-type

When I change output to `stdout { }`
The output seems okay:

```
2017-02-07T13:16:42.000Z MYPC Ähnlicher Fehler mit übermäßger Ödnis
2017-02-08T13:13:52.000Z MYPC ästhetisch überfällige Fleißarbeit
```

### Querying without Kibana

I also queried against the index using this `PowerShell`-command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest –Method POST -Uri 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-clientlogs/_search' -Body '
{
  "query":
  {
    "regexp": {
      "message" : ".*" 
    }
  }
}
' | select -ExpandProperty Content
```

But it also returns the same messed up contents Kibana reveals:

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"logstash-clientlogs","_type":"clientlogs","_id":"AVskdTS8URonc
bfBgFwC","_score":1.0,"_source":{"severity":"Critical","debug":"timestampMatched","message":"�hnlicher Fehler mit �berm��ger �dnis\r","type":"clientlogs","path":"D:/logs/Client.log","@timestamp":"2017-02-07T13:16:42.000Z","granularity":"General","@version":"1","host":"MYPC","timestamp":"2017-02-07 14:16:42"}},{"_index":"logstash-clientlogs","_type":"clientlogs","_id":"AVskdTS8UR
oncbfBgFwD","_score":1.0,"_source":{"severity":"Critical","debug":"timestampMatched","message":"�sthetisch �berf�llige Flei�arbeit\r","type":"clientlogs","path":"D:/logs/Client.log","@timestamp":"2017-02-08T13:13:52.000Z","granularity":"General","@version":"1","host":"MYPC","timestamp":"2017-02-08 14:13:52"}}]}}
```

Has anyone else experienced this and has a solution for this use-case? I don't see any setting for [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to specify any encoding (the file I am passing is `UTF-8 with BOM`) and encoding for input itself does not seem necessary, because it gets me the correct message when I leave out the filter.

Comment: Hi. I can not reproduce this with stdout/stdin. Could you output it to stdout/rubydebug to see if this is indeed a filter problem? I tried both grok and mutate in a similar example to yours

Comment: @pandaadb You are right, output to console looks fine (see update) Should I upload my file somewhere,any other ideas how to isolate the issue?

Comment: Hi, next step: Download the document in question from the ES api, not going through Kibana and check if the indexed document is correct

Comment: @pandaadb Sorry I am fairly new to this. Is there another quick way to do this except for querying using the Developer Console from Kibana? When I do a query there it also looks the same. (messed up like the discover-view in Kibana)

Comment: Going through kibana might just be the problem here, that is why i wanted you to use a different tool, e.g. curl, to get a document. You can grab the doc-id from kibana and then follow this guide for retrieving the actual document directly https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/get-doc.html If the document is correct, your problem is kibana not having the right encoding, if it isn't your indexing/logstash output is screwing with the index. I am leaning towards kibana/the web browser being the culprit here

Comment: @pandaadb Ah yea, was a bit stuck there for a moment, I queried using powershell and it also looks messed up from there ;( (will update this into the post, too)

Comment: I wonder if powershell has issues displaying the content or if it is really messed up. I am starting to blame windows :) you can use chrome and go to the URL you are querying, chrome auto-detects encodings. Apart from that, you can set the codec in the file input and the es output to make sure as: `codec => plain { charset => 'UTF-8' }`

Comment: Unfortunately, setting codecs in input and output also did not change anything. Output in chrome is the same ;( Hopefully it's not good ol' Windows, but I tend to agree with you, most documentation being targeted towards linux, etc. :)

Comment: yes sadly i am getting to the end of my wits here :/ I can not reproduce it locally (I indexed and looked at my kibana + used 2 separate versions of logstash). It sounds like either the output plugin is doing something wrong (weirdly the stdout works though) or the index mechanism of ES itself uses a different encoding to read (so you send correctly but indexing breaks). One more thing to try: use curl to index an Umlaut word manually, e.g. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html This will tell you if this is a logstash problem.